# How to store and sort numbers ever appeared without large memory?

Tags: algorithm, unique

The program give me lots of integers range from 0 to about 2^n_qubits, and have the same hamming weight. The code below just give a simple example, I can't control the random number generator, and it's also not uniform random sampling. In my case I only get randomly generated numbers, and need to give a result set that contain all number that ever appeared.

Let me talk about the variables in my code, the n_e may change in range(1, n_q), and n_q can be 30 or more. Actually, I want algorithm that can deal with larger n_qubits and n_e = n_q//2, that's my research.
The number of integers did't appeared is less than that of appeared, as it's not uniformly sampling, differ from my example code.
And I need to frequently insert elements to the data structure if the element never appeared, so the data structure should be efficient to do insertion operator.

Are there good algorithms both in time efficiency and memory efficiency?
Before, as the code showed, I store all integers, then sort it and combine the duplicate adjacent integers, but it need large memory. The sorted result array's length may be only 1% of that of all integers array in some case.
I also get some idea about hash and binary tree, but don't know how is the performance, need help. (I worry about the overhead of hash function)
And are there good algorithms recommend?
Thank you in advance!

Below is julia code.

```
function get_basis(N_e, n_qubits::Int64) # get set of numbers of same hamming weight N_e in n_qubits bits
    basis_num::Int64 = factorial(big(n_qubits))/factorial(big(N_e))/factorial(big(n_qubits-N_e))
    basis_set = Array{Int64, 1}(undef, basis_num)
    count::Int64 = 0
    for i in 0:(2^n_qubits-1)
        if count_ones(i) == N_e
            count += 1
            basis_set[count] = i
        end
    end
    return basis_set
end

n_e = 4
n_q = 10
basis_set = get_basis(n_e, n_q)
set_len = length(basis_set)

res_len = set_len * 4
res_set = Array{Int64, 1}(undef, res_len)
for i in 1:res_len
    res_set[i] = basis_set[rand(1:set_len)]
end

sort!(res_set)

function combine!(my_set::Vector{Int64})
    r::Int64 = 1
    l::Int64 = 1       # length of processed part
    i::Int64 = my_set[r]    # row-index of current element
    tot_num::Int64 = length(my_set)
    # main loop
    while r < tot_num
        r += 1
        i2 = my_set[r]
        if i2 != i  # advance l, and move r-th to l-th
            l += 1
            i = i2
            if l < r
                my_set[l] = i
            end
        end
    end
    if l < tot_num
        resize!(my_set, l)
    end
end

combine!(res_set)
println(res_set) # res_set is what I want get
```

I give a python code too

```
import math
import random

def get_basis(N_e, n_qubits):
    basis_num = math.comb(n_qubits, N_e)
    basis_set = []

    val = 2**N_e - 1
    basis_set.append(val)
    for i in range(basis_num - 1):
        c = val & -val
        r = val + c
        val = (((r^val) >> 2) // c) | r
        basis_set.append(val)
    
    return basis_set

n_e = 4
n_q = 10
basis_set = get_basis(n_e, n_q)
set_len = len(basis_set)

res_len = set_len * 4
res_set = []
for i in range(res_len):
    res_set.append(basis_set[random.randint(0, set_len-1)])


res_set.sort()

def combine(my_set):
    r = 0
    l = 0      # length of processed part
    i = my_set[r]   # row-index of current element
    tot_num = len(my_set)
    # main loop
    while r < tot_num-1:
        r += 1
        i2 = my_set[r]
        if i2 != i:  # advance l, and move r-th to l-th
            l += 1
            i = i2
            if l < r:
                my_set[l] = i
    
    return my_set[:l+1]

res_set = combine(res_set)
print(res_set) # res_set is what I want get
```

Comment: Why did you delete your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77045387/how-to-store-and-sort-numbers-ever-appeared-without-large-memory)? A lot of people took their time to give you really good advice. How do you expect this question to fare any better than the previous one when you've simply copied it with no changes?

Answer (score 0):

So, you in any case need all the the numbers. The best memory solution would be only in case you controlled your random generator: in the case your algorithm would be the storage, and you could use it to retrieve the next number in the sequence. But you don't.

**You can start with red-black tree map with keys as your numbers** to be stored and values as their count. So in case you got duplicates, they just increasing the value. It also benefits you to get the result sorted: just natively traverse the tree giving all `key` by `value` times. Performance would be pretty good: O(log(N)) for inserting average, O(log(N)) for searching if given number presents in map, O(N)  traversing resulting map to get sorted array, so O(N*log(N)) for the entire solution.

Of course, it is not the best possible solution. Advanced approach could be composed using information about your distribution: **make binary search tree arranged not by value, but by probability** of it's appearance to make addition faster (more probable value inserts with maximum speed, less probable with penalty. But it heavily depends on your distribution and may help or get things worse.

Similar approach could be made by hashing if you could in relatively low cost **align your hash with you distribution**, maybe by using good polynomial approximation. Motivation is to get O(1) insertion more probable for more probable outcome and let it lag on thin tails. If the tails of the distribution are fat, you are in trouble.

More complex approach up to tricky archiving may also be imagined.